# Issues in classic asp map function

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I created a map using classic ASP.

When I run this code, it shows

Error Type:
Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A01A8)
Object required: ''
/alertid/new.asp, line 187

I am new to classic asp, can anyone help me please?

Comment: What is at line 187 of new.asp?

Answer (score 1):

If the source you link to is new.asp you have on line 187

```
do while not getlocation.eof
```

Getlocation looks like it should be an ADODB.Recordset object, however you don't appear to have created one or even connected to a database at an earlier point in your code

You probably need to read a tutorial on database connections in Classic ASP.  Here's a link to one, there are plenty of others

http://webcheatsheet.com/asp/database_connection_to_MSSQL.php

Comment: True, just copy&paste of some partial code one find somewhere, without understanding what it's for, usually ends with errors. :)